# proxychains LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded

Tags: 12.04, proxy, libraries, ld

Using proxychains to do apt-get update in ubuntu 12.04.2

```
sudo proxychains  apt-get update
```

gives following error

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libproxychains.so.3' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: I've found the solution,
the execution file in `/usr/bin/proxychains` contains a link to LD_PRELOAD, which should not be `libproxychains.so.3` but should be `libproxychains.so`. Of course, assuming you have `/usr/lib/libproxychains.so` correctly linking to `/usr/lib/libproxychains.so.3`

Answer (score 18):

You must change

```
export LD_PRELOAD=libproxychains.so.3
```

to

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libproxychains.so.3
```

in **/usr/bin/proxychains**

or use `find /usr/lib/ -name libproxychains.so.3 -print` to get the right file path.

Comment: In peppermint 4.0, it should be /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3

Comment: "proxychains-ng" or proxychains4 have no problem like this.

Comment: If setting `proxy_dns`, the same needs to be done to `\`which proxyresolv\`` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Although the error goes away when setting

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libproxychains.so.3
```

in **/usr/bin/proxychains** there is no such file in that location on Ubuntu.
the **link** resides in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ on a 64bit system and /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ (i think) on a 32bit system. The link points to the **file** libproxychains.so.3.0.0 in the same directory. The change should be

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3
```

if on 64bit

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3
```

if on 32bit Ubuntu and derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3
```

did not work. I also added this line to my `.bashrc` and refreshed it by `source ~/.bashrc`

**Solution:**
You need to add/edit it to `proxychains` by:

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/proxychains
```

if on 32bit Ubuntu and derivatives, replace `x86_64-linux-gnu` with `i386-linux-gnu`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add

> export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3

in `.bashrc` instead of run `proxychains bash` in terminal.